# Show data from particular item of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently pulling data from an object.

```
function getData() {
  var data = [
    {
      animalname: "Cheetah",
      id: 1,
      sci_name: "Acinonyx jubatus"
    },
    {
      animalname: "Lion",
      id: 2,
      sci_name: "African Lion"
    }
  ];

  showInfo(data);
}

getData();


function showInfo(data) {

  var chartdiv = document.querySelector(".test");
  // console.log("data: ", data);
  data.forEach( function(data) {

    // card
    var card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add("card");

    //content
    var content = document.createElement('div');
    content.classList.add('content');
    content.innerHTML = data.animalname;

    // append
    chartdiv.appendChild(card);
    card.appendChild(content);
  });
}
```

I'm able to display the data in 'cards' through a forEach.

What I try to achieve is to display additional data from an item, for example the data.sci_name, or the data.id. But I want to show that in another created div with the id of "chosen-card". See my see my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kleefaan/yco02xpg/1/). Best case I would like to create that content of the "chosen-card" onclick of a particular card, and show that particular additional data in the newly created div.

How do I display that additional data from the particular card? Thnx in advance for looking into it.

Comment: Because of the nature of javascript, you can simply append the data (forEach-parameter) to the card-object `card._data = data;` (that's the hacky way). Or you can add the index of a data-entry to a custom attribute and reselect the data from that index at the time, the event occure.

Answer (score 0):

Struggling to understand the question but to retrieve the object in array (WHERE) you can use array#find, this allows you to find in an array without index.
usage:

```
var array = [{name: "Shanon", age: 24}, {name: "John", age: 40}, {name: "Man", age: 50}]
array.find(function(element) {
    return element.name === "Shanon"
})
```